# How can I use a conditional mapped type to make one field special

Tags: typescript

The following code doesn't compile, but from what I understand, it should. How can I create a type that acts like a `Record<string, string | boolean>`, except when the key is a specific value?

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAtgQwOYEtgGkCmBPGBeGAIgBJFVhCBuAWACgpsAHTGAQXxmgCcUwkYAPjABGIEABtMCMDXpMWAIQ7deSANoBdWQ2YwAwhwDeMNehi9OUHnw0AuGGcwAPKJjAATCDB2YQAM3hkNCxcAH4YJXtWAF9ZOlBIWD0ARnsDAmNCJ0J7KwBXFlj48Gh9ACY0oxMyYJw7E0IEQg0YItpixJF7FT5BETFJaQ4UtSzm2QTS4G6rVU1hsrUajDq42kmJTAA6cRAkAAphAEoJks2dvf3gE7ogA)

```js
const magicKey = "$magic";
type A = string | boolean;
type B = string[];
type C = { [K in string]: K extends typeof magicKey ? B : A};

const C1: C = { "x": true };
// Type of computed property's value is 'string[]', which is not assignable to type 'A'.
const C2: C = { [magicKey]: ["a"] };

const b: string | boolean = C1["x"];
const c: string[] = C2[magicKey];

console.log(b);
console.log(c);
```

Comment: You can't, unfortunately. `K in string` doesn't iterate through all possible strings, so `K extends typeof magicKey` will always be false. See the linked q/a for information about your use case, requested at [ms/TS#17867](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/17867), and for the relevant approaches and workarounds.